# questions about limit

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

What is wrong in my solutio ?

Suppose $|f (x)| \le 7x^4$   for all x . What can be said, if anything, about  the following?
 a)   $\lim_ {x\to 0} f(x) $
b)    $\lim_ {x\to 2} f(x) $

Sol: 
a)$ -7x^4 \le f (x) \le 7x^4 $
     $\lim_ {x\to 0} -7x^4 \le \lim_ {x\to 0} f(x) \le \lim_ {x\to 0} f(x) $

$0 \le \lim_ {x\to 0} f(x) \le  0 $

$\lim_ {x\to 0} f(x)  = 0$

b )

$-7x^4 \le f (x) \le 7x^4 $
     $\lim_ {x\to 2} -7x^4 \le \lim_ {x\to 2} f(x) \le \lim_ {x\to 2} f(x) $

$-7 .2^4 \le \lim_ {x\to 0} f(x) \le  7.2^4 $

$\lim_ {x\to 0} f(x) :  undecided$

Thanks so much for all

Comment: Your answer $b$ must be substantiated (and what with $f(x)=0$ for instance ?).

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

for the first it' ok, the limit is $0$

for the second you can't conclude anything but that $$-7 \cdot 2^4 \leq liminf \leq limsup \leq 7 \cdot 2^4$$

[EDIT] I've posed the above inequality in a more clear way

Comment: b )     so  does not exsit by sandwich therom

Comment: it could exist but you can’t be sure, if exists it is between the two extreme values

Answer (score 0):

Since $7\cdot 0^4 = 0$ you know that $|f(x)| \leq 0 $ for $x = 0$. Thus in a nbh of $0$ $f(x)$ will be $\epsilon$-close to $0$, thus the limit is $0$. For $x=2$ you have $|f(x)| \leq 7 \cdot 2^4$, hence the limit (if it exists) is finite.